# sharethis javascript plugin creates space at top of webpage

Tags: html, css, iframe, jscript, sharethis

Sharethis plug in is inserting space at the top of this page https://www.stakeholdermap.com/principles-stakeholder-management.html. If I inspect the page I can see this code (powr is part of/partnered with sharethis).

```
<div id="powrIframeLoader">&shy;<style> .powrLoaded iframe { visibility: hidden; } </style></div>
```

If I comment out the share this code below the space disappears.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://platform-api.sharethis.com/js/sharethis.js#property=649ade7591ef70001294d543&product=sop" async="async"></script>
```

This started happening when I removed navbar-fixed-top from the blue navbar. I don't want the navbar to be fixed anymore so can anyone suggest how to prevent sharethis/powr creating that div at the top of my page?

edit: the space disappears after the page has finished loading.

Comment: disabling the powr plugin from within sharethis.com removes the space.